# GGPLOT in R Line Chart for Time Series Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have following type of data and I want to plot line chart as time series. I have around 25 products in the first column and I need to make separate time series graph for each product. Looking for a solution via ggplot in R please.
Thanks for your help.

```
structure(list(Products = c("Prod_A", "Prod_B", "Prod_C"), `Jan-20` = c(15L, 
1043L, 9L), `Feb-20` = c(20L, 1033L, 1L), `Mar-20` = c(18L, 1890L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA7Kc.png)
[Line chart graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFsGV.png)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is a placeholder for the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually I am not sure how to use dput(). But I already added picture of the data above, please see link Data. Thanks.

Comment: @ClinicalInfo type in ``dput(head(df, 20)`` and then paste the output into your question. Images are not very useful for people who are trying to help. Thanks.

Comment: Ok sure, I will do so. Thanks.